# How to loop number and saved into table laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have input and this input is will generate number sequentially like this

```
5.01
5.02
5.03
......
5.10
5.11
```

i get number 5 on first number is from my another data . u can see at my code .so how i can do this if this number start from '01' not '1' and if more than 10 this '0' in first number is deleted.

in my controller i saved in $data and looping this number from 01
So in my input controller is like that :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{   

    $data = $request['kode_induk'] + // i dont know what to do here for loop this input , 

    $induk = IndukBelanja::create([
       'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
       'kode_induk' => $request['kode_induk'],
       'kode_rekening' => $data,
       'uraian' => $request['uraian'],
       'anggaran' => $request['anggaran'],
    ]);

    if ($induk) {
        return ['redirect' => route('rekening_induk')];
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => ' Gagal update!',
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

how i can loop this number ? can someone help ?

Update its my database what i need

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id |kode_induk  |kode_rekening|   uraian
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |   5        |   5.01     |    some data   
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  2 |   5        |   5.02     |    some data   
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  3 |   5        |   5.03     |    some data 
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  4 |   5        |   5.04     |    some data   
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: I do not understand the question, can you please provide the original data and the expected result?

Comment: oke first i have input . 2  i want to input in colomn kode_rekening is looping  , i mean i want to create like 5.01 , 5.02 , . wait i will show my data

Comment: i update my question

Comment: Can you confirm if `$data` is an array? You can do so with `dd($data)`.

Comment: this data is not completed query , u can see this i dont know what to do

Comment: So `$data` is 5?

Comment: yes , i want to add 01 , 02 , 03 . and this output 5.01

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `$data` to int and then increment by `0.01` in a [`for` loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).

```php
    $data = (int) $request['kode_induk'];
    $numberOfSequencesToGenerate = 10;
    
    for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfSequencesToGenerate; $++){
        $induk = IndukBelanja::create([
           'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
           'kode_induk' => $request['kode_induk'],
           'kode_rekening' => $data + 0.01,
           'uraian' => $request['uraian'],
           'anggaran' => $request['anggaran'],
        ]);
    }
```

The loop basically reads, run the the block of code while `$i` is less than `$numberOfSequencesToGenerate`. On each iteration increment `$i` by one.

I am assuming the DB field `kode_rekening` is of type `double` but if is not you can format it in PHP so is always has two decimal places with [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). Ex: `number_format($data + 0.01, 2)`